# Dojo class similar to ArrayStore in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, dojo

Do we have any Dojo store class similar to ArrayStore in ExtJs? We are migrating one applications, which was developed in ExtJS, to Dojo framwork (version 1.8). We want to keep the service layer untouched as much as possible.
We are getting response from service layer in JSON as

```
response = "{'success': true,'msg': '','Data': [['1','data1','1'],['2','data2','2']]}";
```

In ExtJS, arraystore considers the data in array format and renders it accordingly.
Do we have some class matching my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Check "dojo/store/Memory" which stores collection-binding model and stores array as its 'data' attribute. Also, it provides methods to query, add/update/delete this data.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am able to parse the JSON string and get the "Data" value from it. But when I store the same in "dojo/store/Memory", it is not getting displayed. Do you have any working version of the suggested store or can you provide a sample code to parse the string provided in my question?